# cdn fallback code for amplify.js in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, amplifyjs

I know that following code is used for fallback of jquery from cdn to local.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

What is the similar code for fallback of `amplify.js` javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com/) is hosting it

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amplifyjs/1.1.0/amplify.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!window.amplify) {
    document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/amplifyjs"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be different expression check for amplify.js rather than checking for window.jQuery(which is to check if jquery is loaded)?